# Is Python 3.7 the latest available version for readthedocs.io?

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I am using type hints and when I build my docs in readthedocs.io, it tells me "type is not subscriptable". The error refers to `list[str]`.

`def build_pirate_ship(source_path: str=None) -> list[str]:`

This prevents `autodoc` from working. But, if I take out the type hints and build my docs, `autodoc` works flawlessly.

When I look at my build log, it shows Python 3.7 being used. Is there a way to tell readthedocs.io to use a newer version of Python? Preferably 3.11?

Comment: [Looks like you can use 3.11.](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-tools-python)

Comment: @user2357112 Yep, thanks - https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html

Comment: Side-note: Technically, `def build_pirate_ship(source_path: str=None) -> list[str]:` is an invalid annotation. Insofar as you told it `source_path` must always be `str`, then said the default value is `None`. You should be using `def build_pirate_ship(source_path: str|None=None) -> list[str]:`, or if you need to support 3.9 (`list[str]` already requires 3.9, `str|None` needs 3.10), you'd use `def build_pirate_ship(source_path: Optional[str]=None) -> list[str]:` (with `from typing import Optional`). If the empty string is a reasonable default, you can use that with plain `str` annotation.

Comment: For anyone reading @ShadowRanger is referring to making type optional. `|` is for newer versions and built in. So you don't need to import `Optional`. pipe operators for union syntax is a new feature in 3.10, while Optional is older and therefore compatible with more python versions. It's a good point. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here, [docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html)

You create a `.readthedocs.yaml` in the root of your project directory and then the file should look something like,

```
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
    # You can also specify other tool versions:
    # nodejs: "19"
    # rust: "1.64"
    # golang: "1.19"
```